# Float variable != null not working

Tags: java, android

If (loanAmtValue!=null) is used..it throws an error ie."Operator != cannot be applied to float,null". Plzz sum1 come up with a solution to this prob.. The app crashes if no value is given in that field. So I was trying to use null condition check so that app doesn't crash even if no value is given.

```
public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button submit;
    private  Button submit2;
    SeekBar sb;
    TextView yrs;
    EditText loanAmt;
    EditText roi;
    TextView siResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

        final int years;
        sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.set_years);
        yrs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.years);

        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                yrs.setText(sb.getProgress()+" year(s)");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        addButtonClickListener();
    }

    private void addButtonClickListener() {

        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        submit2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        submit2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        float loanAmtValue = 0;
        float roiValue = 0;
        double answer=0;
        float y = sb.getProgress();

        loanAmt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amt);
        loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmt.getText().toString());
        roi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roi);
        roiValue = Float.parseFloat(roi.getText().toString());

        if (loanAmtValue != null && roiValue != null){


                case R.id.button:
                    answer = (loanAmtValue * roiValue * y) / 100;

                    siResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                    siResult.setText("Simple Interest for Amount Rs." + loanAmtValue + " and ROI " + roiValue + "% for "+y+" year(s) is = " + String.format("%.2f", answer));

                    loanAmt.setText("0");
                    roi.setText("0");
                    break;

            }


        }
        else
        {
            siResult.setText("Please provide valid details");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `"Operator != cannot be applied to float,null"` means?

Comment: you can't compare floats as they're a primative and not an object!

Comment: @Michael Goldstein can you show me how it can be done in this piece of code?

Comment: Keeping in mind that **null != 0** (really, no joke!), change `if (loanAmtValue != null && roiValue != null){` to `if (loanAmtValue != 0.0f && roiValue != 0.0f){`

Comment: @Der Golem I did this..but if no value is given then app crashes. It only checks whether it is 0 or not...this is not wht I am looking for

Comment: But you then have a different error. Which one?

Comment: Is there any way to check error when the app crashes..I am new to this ..

Comment: Use the **logcat**, Luke!

Comment: @user645, Der Golem is correct. You should says `!= 0` because float variables cannot equal `null`. So if your app crashes even when you change it to `!= 0`, then you have an error which occurs either after or within the if-statement.

Comment: App works if I use !=0 ..so its implied dat if no value is passed..it crashes...dat is y..I am looking for sumthin wich will check wether loanAmtValue is empty or not..plz come up with solutn 2 dis..if dis is cleared..i am done

Comment: Could you please **speak correctly**? plz, dis, solutn, dat, sumthin... **don't use SMS style here**, please.

Answer (score 4):

`float` is a primitive data type and not an object. `null` check is used for objects.

For primitives you should use the default values check. For float the default value is `0.0f`.

Read following:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-default-values/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your problem is here :

```
loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmt.getText().toString());
```

This line will throw NumberFormatException if `loanAmt` doesn't contain a String that can be converted to a float.

You can check that the String is not empty before attempting to convert to float :

```
if (loanAmt.getText() != null && !loanAmt.getText().isEmpty()) {
    loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmt.getText().toString());
}
```

This would still throw an exception if the user enters an invalid String, so you'll have to catch the exception :

```
if (loanAmt.getText() != null && !loanAmt.getText().isEmpty()) {
    try {
        loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmt.getText().toString());
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        loanAmtValue = 0.0; // or some other default value
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! One little tweak, one of my favorite little Android treats is to use `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(loanAmt.getText()))` instead of `if (loanAmt.getText() != null && !loanAmt.getText().isEmpty())` :)

Comment: @ScottW That's a good idea. I'm less familiar with the Android utility classes, so I didn't know this method exists, though I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Null is used for objects. If an object is null, then this means this variable points to nowhere.

```
Obj a = null // a points nowhere
a = new Obj() // now a points to a place in the memory (a references an Obj object in the memory
```

And float is not an object type, it's a primitive type. But be carefull if you make comparison like: x == 0.0 (float comparison is not like comparison integers!).

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answers, You cannot check if a float is null, like everybody said here. What You can do is, like "Der Golem" said check it if it is !=0, if You want to get sure that the value is not 0 (not the same like null!!!). BUT:

To prevent  a NumberFormatException You also have to be sure, that Your catched value from the edit text field is a number. You can do it with TextUtils:

```
  android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence str).
```

In Your case, You should do it like this:

```
    loanAmt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amt);

    String loanAmtString = loanAmt.getText().toString();
    if(android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(loanAmtString)){
    loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmtString);
    }

    roi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roi);
    String roiString = roi.getText().toString();

    if(android.text.TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(roiString)){
    roiValue = Float.parseFloat(roiString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two ways to enforce user to enter only float values.

1. Using `inputType` for `EditText`
2. Checking entered text by a regular expression

   ```
   Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("^\\d*\\.\\d*$");
   String enteredText = ...;

   if(ptrn.matcher(enteredText).matches()){
       // try to parse the string here
   }
   ```